# PHP MYSQL PDO lastInsertId is returning 0 when using a procedure to insert rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, last-insert-id

I keep getting zero for LastInsertedID, I think it is because I am using a mysql stored procedure. Here is my code:

```
// Set up a new MYSQL PDO Database Connection
$dbConnection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database;charset=UTF8', 'username', 'password');
//turn off emulation for prepared statement and set error mode option
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

//Create a statement and prepare it with parameters
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("CALL AddMovieSet(:UserID, :SelectedLibraryID, :txtName, :txtNotes);");
$stmt->bindValue(':UserID', $_SESSION["UserID"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':SelectedLibraryID', $_SESSION["SelectedLibraryID"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':txtName', $_GET["txtName"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':txtNotes', $_GET["txtNotes"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
//execute the prepared statement
$stmt->execute();

//the stored procedure successfully inserts a row
$Name=$_GET["txtName"];
$Notes=$_GET["txtNotes"];
$InsertedID=$dbConnection->lastInsertId(); 
//$InsertedID is always zero, the table I am inserting a row into has an AUTO_INCREMENT for the first column.
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes PHP and PDO can be buggy with `lastInsertID()` and stored procedures. Try using this MySQL call instead:

```
"SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();"
```